# Searching code files for a particular string

Tags: unix, search, ubuntu

Im using Ubuntu Karmic as my operating system . I frequently need to search my project folder for a particular string, to see if its there in any of the files in the project folder or its subfolders.
I currently use the find command to do that, and have written a script that accepts the string im looking for as the parameter.

```
find . -exec grep -l $1 {} \;
```

But the problem with this is that it does not work with strings having a space in them. So, is there any way to search for space separated strings as well, or is there any available tool that does the job ?

Thank You.

Comment: I believe enclosing the string in double quotes and backticks should work. "\`some string\`"

Comment: Sounds like maybe you should be exploring [`ctags`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) et al.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you invoking your script?

If you want to search for space separated strings you need to do the
invocation in the form:

`%./script_name.sh 'search string'`

and also change the find invocation to :

find . -exec grep -l "$1" {} \;

Answer (score 1):

A better version of that command is simply `grep -rl "$1" .`, or possibly `grep -rl "$*" .`.

If your string contains the correct amount of space, and the problem is simply the shell parsing the arguments, then you can refer to every arg with `"$*"` and you can prevent the shell from breaking at word boundaries (but still allow parameter expansion) by using the *soft* double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may simply do `grep -lR ${1} .` to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -R "phrase with spaces" /folder/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -type d -name "folder name" 2> /dev/null
```